# Whats the value of the boolean expression

Tags: c++, boolean

Consider the following c++ code

```
bool p = false, q = false, r = true;

bool another = p && q;
cout << another; // another =false now

cout << another || r;  //false || true should be true
```

the compiler output as 0(false) but how. I expect it as 1(true)

thanks

Comment: Use brackets to force the compiler to evaluate things as you want. This doesn't happen here.

Comment: Relevant search term: "Operator Precedence".

Comment: strange. but why would it be necessary even to display an with  single operator to put it into brackets

Comment: @Curious I just said the reason: Operator precedence. Did you try looking it up?

Answer (score 4):

`<<` operator has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `||`, therefore the compiler interprets it as

```
(cout << another) || r;
```

Comment: cout << (another || r);

Comment: @hkg328 Yes, that's what the OP wants, but this is what the compiler read instead.